# how to back out of upgrading grub

Tags: apt, grub2

I just made a huge mistake of doing apt-get update followed by apt-get upgrade on my linode ubuntu instance. From previous experience, anything you do to upgrade GRUB will kill the server, as there are special additions in the existing files which are linode specific, and if you oveerwrite them, you cannot boot the server.  When It poped up with the message asking if I wanted to keep the existing file or overwrite it, I looked for an option to cancel and/or abort.  There is none.  So i did the next best thing and hit CTRL-C. This then jumps to the next section which asks which of the 4 patitions it should write to. Again, no option to cancel or aport, and ctrl-C does not work.

This is the message I now face:

```
 │ The GRUB boot loader was previously installed to a disk that is no longer          │ 
 │ present, or whose unique identifier has changed for some reason. It is important   │ 
 │ to make sure that the installed GRUB core image stays in sync with GRUB modules    │ 
 │ and grub.cfg. Please check again to make sure that GRUB is written to the          │ 
 │ appropriate boot devices.                                                          │ 
 │                                                                                    │ 
 │ If you're unsure which drive is designated as boot drive by your BIOS, it is       │ 
 │ often a good idea to install GRUB to all of them.                                  │ 
 │                                                                                    │ 
 │ Note: it is possible to install GRUB to partition boot records as well, and some   │ 
 │ appropriate partitions are offered here. However, this forces GRUB to use the      │ 
 │ blocklist mechanism, which makes it less reliable, and therefore is not            │ 
 │ recommended.                                                                       │ 
 │                                                                                    │ 
 │ GRUB install devices:                                                              │ 
 │                                                                                    │ 
 │    [ ] /dev/sda (686926 MB; QEMU_HARDDISK)                                         │ 
 │    [ ] /dev/sdb (268 MB; QEMU_HARDDISK)                                            │ 
 │    [ ] /dev/sdc (322122 MB; Volume)                                                │ 
 │    [ ] /dev/sda (686926 MB; QEMU_HARDDISK)                                                                                        │ 
 │                                       <Ok>
```

Obviously, I dont want to write to any of them, but there is no option for this.  So i did CTRL-Z followed by ps and kill of the pid.

What should I have done to go back?

Comment: You *should* back up any custom files you have and when asked choose to keep the existing file

Comment: I do not understand how grub is related to linode. But if not using grub how are you booting. And getting grub in MBR/core.img out of sync with install is one of the major reasons systems will not boot. But if you do not want updates see this: `man dpkg` and the hold option. This should be where grub-pc on updates will install: `sudo debconf-show grub-pc`